# Remove index.php from www.domain.com/abc/index.php/xyz

Tags: url-rewrite, redirect, htaccess

**What's happening:**

`domain.com/abc/index.php/xyz` gets redirected to `www.domain.com/abc/index.php/xyz`

**I'd like:**

`domain.com/abc/index.php/xyz` gets redirected to `www.domain.com/abc/xyz`

In the document root directory of a Magento installation, I have the following to redirect `domain.com/...` to `www.domain.com/...`, and `index.php` is never there.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

However, there's a sub-directory that contains static pages at `root/abc`. This directory has its own `.htaccess` file, and I've put the same rewrite condition and rule as above. It also have the following. I'm not sure what the first two conditions are doing. The `RewriteRule` seems like it should remove the index.php.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /corps/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Check [this](https://www.hellothemes.com/blog/how-to-remove-index-php-from-your-magento-urls/) guide, it has the solution for your issue.
You have to change your .htaccess to have this inside:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ – [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: Does this work for the subdirectory of the root? FYI, I already have `index.php` removed from all URLs except for the `domain.com/abc/index.php/...`.

Comment: I think they need `RewriteBase /abc/`

Comment: If one also wants to redirect /index.php/ URLs to URLs without it, then see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47833648/magento-redirect-urls-with-index-php-to-urls-without-it

Answer (score 1):

The 3th line from

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /corps/index.php/$1 [L]
```

causes the url to have `index.php` in it. The first 2 lines ensure existing files and directories are not redirected.

Change it to below and you should be good

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /corps/$1 [L]
```